# quote getAllItems returns empty array

Tags: magento2, quote

```
 public function getItems(){
    $a=array();
    $customerId = null;
    $userType = GroupInterface::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID;
    $isGuest = true;
    $quote = null;
    if($this->isLoggedIn()){
        $customerId = $this->userContext->getUserId();
        $isGuest = false;
        $quote = $this->cartObj->getQuote()->loadByCustomer($customerId);

    }
    else{
        $quote = $this->cartObj->getQuote();
        $quote->setCustomerGroupId(GroupInterface::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
    }
    $quote->setCustomerIsGuest($isGuest);
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        array_push($a,$item->getData());
        /*$a[$i]['ProductId'] = $item->getProductId();*/           
    }
    //array_push($a,$items);
    return $a;
}
```

this code returns me empty result even te cart is not empty and when I call

```
  $quote->getItemsCount();
```

it returns me 4.

why this is happening

Comment: have you tried using checkout session for quote

Comment: @AmanAlam yes, same result

Comment: Are you trying in block or controller or just in script?

Comment: in model, I'm building api

Comment: Ok will check by dry run and let you know if there is way your magento version

Comment: Are you getting empty array for logged in customers or both logged in and guests?

Comment: put the line of code $quote->setCustomerIsGuest($isGuest); inside the else {} condition.

Comment: @MGento for logged in customer ... no need to move that line to else block, I changed the value of the boolean $isGuest according to the condition

Comment: is this problem happening in your localhost? if so try to access the project using local ip address instead of localhost

Comment: did you find the fix?